# Checking exclusion restriction IV assumption

Tags: causality, instrumental-variables

Assume, we have the following:

$Y$- outcome

$D$- exposure

$U$- unobserved confounder

$V$- instrumental variable.

Assume there are no observed confounders.

Can we check the assumption of exclusion restriction by running a regression of $Y$ on $D$ and $V$ and testing if the coefficient associated with $V$ is 0? The rational is all the effects of $V$ on $Y$ has to go through $D$ so once $D$ is controlled, there should be no effect of $V$.

Comment: This has come up several times before. Here's [one example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152956/is-the-key-assumption-for-instrumental-variables-not-testable/152987#152987).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can we check the assumption of exclusion restriction by running a
>   regression of Y on D and V and testing if the coefficient associated
>   with V is 0?

No, you can't. It's easy to see why visually. Consider the DAG below, representing your set up:

[image]

Your proposal is to regress $Y$ on $D$ and $V$ and check if the coefficient of $V$ is zero. But look what happens if you condition $D$:

[image]

That is, even though you have blocked the directed path $V \rightarrow D \rightarrow Y$, you now [opened the path](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/330943/d-separation-from-a-given-hard-evidence-on-b-and-e/330972#330972) $V \rightarrow D \leftarrow U \rightarrow Y$ (represented in red)! The treatment, in this case, acts as a collider, and conditioning on it opens the mentioned spurious path.

Thus, we should not expect the regression coefficient of $Y$ on $V$ conditional on $D$ to be zero *even if* $V$ is a valid instrument.